# regular expression that matches on at least one alphabetic character

Tags: python, regex

I'm not familiar with regular expressions and am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
reg=re.compile('[a-zA-z]+?') #regular expression checks for at least one alphabetic character

print(bool(reg.match('*ab*')))
```

I would like this to result in True. It doesn't matter where the alphabetic character occurs in the string.

Comment: `match` always tries to match at beginning of string, use `search` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your pattern if you want to keep `compile` and `match`:

```
re.compile('.*[A-Za-z].*')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check your matches by using the re.match function.

Here is a doc on it: https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html

```
import re

string = "someWord"

Output = re.match('[a-zA-z]+?', string)

if Output:
    print('match found')
```

Comment: This still results in an output of False for the example I gave.

Comment: Can you send us what your input is?

Comment: I used '*ab*' but another user answered already, I should have been using search() instead of match()